# MyFirebaseMessagingServiceservice is not assignable to android.app.service

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Messaging Service is Causing Crash in My App. When i Implement FirebaseMessagingService and try to add it on Manifest its showing me "MyFirebaseMessagingServiceservice is not assignable to android.app.service" . When I didn't use the MyFirebaseMessagingServiceservice , then also im getting the error. This question is asked before, I have tried all the answer given in that question but noting workout. Please help.
Im using firebase-messaging:17.1.0
This is the error-

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com.example.genesishospital.MyFirebaseMessagingService
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3838)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap8(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1909)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding this permission my app works fine.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```